# PowerShell NuGet - "no match was found for the specified search criteria", "unable to find dependent packages", etc

Tags: powershell, package, nuget, jwt

I was trying to install the assembly System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, but I keep getting nuget errors:

`find-package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name
'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.`

When I download the .nupkg file directly and try to install it that way, I get the following error:

`Install-Package : Unable to find dependent package(s) (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens)`

What am I doing wrong? I am a linux person normally so my instinct is that I am lacking the appropriate repositories, but I couldn't figure out how to resolve that issue.

Comment: check `Get-PackageSource` because the stuff you're looking for isn't in the default PSGallery repo.  I think you're going to need to sort out where you expect to be getting the modules from before any of the packages you mentioned will resolve as expected.

Comment: Get-PackageSource tells me I only have PowerShellGet. How can I find which repository I need to add for this assembly? That is the step I was having trouble with.

Answer (score 21):

That was a bit difficult to find, but here is my solution. If the `Get-PackageSource` tells you that there is no NuGet registered as a package source then we register it first:

`Register-PackageSource -provider NuGet -name nugetRepository -location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2`

After that it should work.

I had another issue though. I did have NuGet registered but apparently, this PowerShell cmdlet expects to work with the v2 API version of NuGet, while I had v3 registered. There are 2 solutions to that: either re-register the correct version, for that

`Unregister-PackageSource -Name nuget.org` (check the name first) and then register the correct version using the earlier command

OR

specify the correct API version in the Find (and other) commands explicitly:

`Find-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2`. There is an [issue on Gihub](https://github.com/OneGet/NuGetProvider/issues/28) that provides this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$_nugetUrl = "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" 
$packageSources = Get-PackageSource
if(@($packageSources).Where{$_.location -eq $_nugetUrl}.count -eq 0)
{
   Register-PackageSource -Name MyNuGet -Location $_nugetUrl -ProviderName NuGet
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On pwsh (powershell core) you can pass the necessary package source URL in the `-Source` parameter to the `Install-Package` command.

This way you don't have to register a global package source.

Example:

```
Install-Package -Force Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Tools.NETCore `
                -Destination "/tmp/mypackages" `
                -Source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"
```